# Find Derivative Using a Table of Values

Tags: calculus

Yes, this is a homework problem :), so I'm not looking for the answer just how to approach it.
[Find derivative using a table of values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZZDK.png)

Comment: Use the product rule.

Comment: Do you know how to find the derivative of h(x)?

Comment: Calculate $h'(x)$ using the *properties* of derivatives. Use the table to get the *values* required to find $h'(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$h(x)=xf(x)+2g(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}h(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x) + 2g(x))$$

Distributing the derivative we get this main equation:

$$\frac{d}{dx}h(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))+\frac{d}{dx}(2g(x)) $$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(xf(x))=f(x)+x\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)$$

Plug this into the main equation and simplify, to get:

$$\frac{d}{dx}h(x)=[f(x)+xf'(x)]+[2g'(x)] $$

Now you can find all the values on the right hand side of the above equation in the table give. So just substitute to get the  value of $h'(x)$.

Comment: I guess I'm not sure why the product rule had to be used here? Because x is a variable in the xf(x) term?

Comment: Whenever we have f(x).g(x), and we need to differentiate the entire expression w.r.t. to $x$, we have to use the product rule. Take a simple example, of $f(x)=(5x+1)$ and try to derive d/dx (x.(5x+1). You will find that the product rule has to be applied. I could explain more.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. I thought it only applied to functions, although I guess x could be considered to be the same as f(x)=x, so there you go.

Comment: $f(x)=x$ is a function indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Note:

1. $\frac{dh}{dx}(a)=\left.\frac{dh}{dx}\right|_{x=a}$ i.e. derivative
   evaluated at given point $a$ (differentiating with respect to $x$
   and then evaluating the function at $a$.
2. Product rule of differentiation:

   $\frac{d}{dx} (u\cdot v) = v \cdot \frac{du}{dx} + u \cdot 
   \frac{dv}{dx}$

Only these two concepts are required to solve your problem.
Apply the product rule to differentiate and then evaluate the function obtained at the given point.